# Different results for simulated and closed form distribution of T-statistic under the alternative hypothesis

Tags: p-value, statistical-power, t-distribution, non-central, gpower

While running some simulations to get a better grasp of the concept of statistical power I stumbled upon an unexpected result. I was trying to simulate the sampling distribution of test statistic $T$ associated with Pearson correlation coefficient $R$, assuming a sample size of $n = 200$ and a population correlation $\rho = .5$. I expected that this distribution would look like a non-central $T$-distribution with noncentrality parameter $ \lambda = \sqrt{\frac{n \rho^2}{1-\rho^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{200*0.5^2}{1-0.5^2}}=8.164966$ ([which is the distribution used in G*Power to calculate statistical power under these circumstances](http://www.psychologie.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPowerManual.pdf); see page 41 of the manual). However, the distribution I got from my simulation did not at all resemble the plot of the noncentral $pdf$. This is the plot:

[image: Distribution of T]

The R code I used is:

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 200
rho <- 0.5
noncentrality <- sqrt(((rho**2)*n)/(1-(rho**2)))

tdistsim <- c()
for (i in 1:10000) {
  Variable1 <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  Variable2 <- rho*Variable1+rnorm(n,0,1)
  tdistsim[i] <- cor.test(Variable1,Variable2,method="pearson")$statistic
} 

pdft <- dt(seq(0,15,15/10000),df=n-2,ncp=noncentrality)
plot(seq(0,15,15/10000),pdft,type="l",col="blue",lwd=3,xlab=c("T"),ylab=c("Density"))
lines(density(tdistsim),col="red",lwd=3)
legend(0,0.32,
       c("Noncentral pdf","Simulation"),
       lwd="3",
       col=c("blue","red")
)
```

So, obviously, my question is: how is this possible? Aren't these distributions supposed to be (nearly/asymptotically) identical? And if so, where's my error?

**EDIT.** I think I found the error in my simulation. The standard deviation of the residuals was set to 1 instead of $RMSE = \sqrt{1-\rho^2}$. That is, the line

```
Variable2 <- rho*Variable1+rnorm(n,0,1)
```

should read

```
Variable2 <- rho*Variable1+rnorm(n,0,sqrt(1-rho**2))
```

The plot now looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: Where exactly in the G*Power manual can we find the cited formula?

Comment: Page 41. Sorry, will add this to the opening post as well.

Comment: Re the edit: Do you have a question left to ask?

Comment: I don't think so - not unless someone spots another error somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: What this doesn't resolve is the question about the sampling distribution of the $t$ statistic when you have an arbitrary residual standard deviation, as in your first simulation where you set it to 1.

Comment: @COOLSerdash. Thanks, but could you clarify? My question was about the t-statistic associated with a correlation coefficient. If I'm not mistaken, to interpret rho within the model above as a correlation the (in)dependent variables require mean 0 and variance 1. The only way to guarantee a variance of 1 in Variable2 is by setting the residual standard deviation of the linear model to RMSE= sqrt(1−ρ²). After all, the variance of a sum of independent normals is the sum of the variance of those normals, and the variance of ρ*Variable1 = ρ²*1. Thus, the variance of Variable2 will be 1−ρ²+ρ² = 1.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was asking the question: "What is the sampling distribution of the $t$ statistic when we have an arbitrary bivariate normal distribution (arbitrary correlation and variances).". I've just did some simulations and the formula given in the G*Power manual seems to be correct in these cases too. So it's all good. Sorry for the confusion.